# $X_n \to_p X$, $X>0$ a.s., what further conditions are needed on $X$ to show that $P(X_nX > 0) \to 1$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

We have a sequence of random variables $X_n$, $n = 1,2,...$ which converges in probability to $X$, where $X>0$ a.s. and we want to find further conditions on $X$ to get that $P(X_nX > 0) \to 1$. I understand this boils down to finding conditions under which $P(X_n > 0) \to 1$ since

$$
P(X_nX >0) = P(X_nX>0|X>0) = P(X_n>0).
$$

My first approach is the following, for all $\varepsilon >0$ and by monotonicity of probability measures

$$
P(|X_n - X| \leq \varepsilon) = P(-\varepsilon \leq X_n-X \leq \varepsilon) \leq P(X_n \geq X-\varepsilon).
$$

By convergence in probability $P(|X_n - X| \leq \varepsilon) \to 1$ and so $P(X_n \geq X-\varepsilon) \to 1$. However, this does not seem to be enough since $X>0$ a.s. does not ensure that $X - \varepsilon > 0$. Hence I think a sufficient condition would be to assume that $X > \eta$ a.s. for some $\eta > 0$. Under this condition we can repeat the argument above for $\varepsilon = \eta$ and we would get

$$
P(|X_n - X| \leq \eta) \leq P(X_n \geq X-\eta) \leq P(X_n > 0) \to 1.
$$

Hence, am I right and is $X>\eta$ a.s. for some $\eta >0$ enough? Finally, could it be relaxed to some condition that limits the amount of mass around zero, for example that for any $\varepsilon >0$ and $\alpha >0$ the mass above $0$ decreases like this:

$$
P(X> \varepsilon) \leq (1/\varepsilon)^\alpha
$$

Comment: $X>\eta$ almost surely is not enough. For example if $X_{n}$ are iid symmetric bernoulli with $P(X_{n}=-1)=\frac{1}{n}$ and $P(X_{n}=1)=1-\frac{1}{n}$ then $X_{n}\xrightarrow{P}X:=1$ but $\{X_{n}X=X_{n}=-1(<0)\,\text{infinitely often}\}$ with probability $1$ due to Borel Cantelli lemma. So $\lim\inf P(X_{n}X>0)=0$ and hence you cannot have convergence.

Comment: I might be wrong but to me it seems that focussing too much on $X$ will not necessarily do you any good. It is the $\lim\inf P(X_{n}X>0)$ that you have to worry about and show that it goes to $0$. Otherwise, $\lim\sup P(X_{n}X>0)$ is always $1$ as along a subsequence, you have almost sure convergence to $X$. Hence, in particular, emphasis should be given on how the sequence behaves rather than the limit.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron In yourexample, $P(X_nX>0)=1-\frac 1 n \to 1$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Right. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $\delta$ such that $P(X\leq \delta)<\epsilon$

Now $P(X_nX\leq 0)=P(X_n \leq 0)\leq P(X_n\leq 0, X>\delta)+P(X\leq \delta)$. The first term does not exceed $P(|X_n-X|>\delta)$. Can you finish?

Comment: I think so. So the condition is that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta$ such that $P(X \leq \delta) < \varepsilon$. Then for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we can show $P(X_nX <= 0) \leq P(|X_n - X| > \delta) + \varepsilon$. Then we can just take $\varepsilon = 1/n$ and let $n \to \infty$. This works when the $\delta$ can be the same for all $\varepsilon$ (e.g. $X < \eta$ a.s.), does it work too if $\delta$ depends on $\varepsilon$? then  P(X_nX <= 0) \leq P(|X_n - X| > \delta_\varepsilon) + \varepsilon$ so i guess one needs to impose a rate on the convergence in probability

Comment: First fix $\delta$ for which the second term is less than $\epsilon$. Then choose $n_0$ such that the first term is less than $\epsilon$ for $n \geq n_0$. You get $P(X_nX\leq 0) <2\epsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0$.  @improbable_probabilist